# Why python program run fine on pycharm, but showing syntax error on ubuntu terminal after changing from bash to zsh

Tags: python, bash, zsh

I have some python script, which working fine on ubuntu default bash terminal. When i changed terminal to zsh, python file.py giving following syntax error

```
  File "file.py", line 17
    file_dir: str = ''
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The same file working fine on pycharm build-in run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error looks like you're running it under python 2 rather than python 3. The reason it works in bash but not zsh is probably that your `PATH` is different, which traces back to a difference in the shell's initialization files (i.e. ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc vs ~/.zprofile and ~/.zshrc etc).

You can compare your `PATH` in the two shells by running `echo "$PATH"` in each, and see what python executables each is finding with `type -a python` (it may list several different executables; the first on the list is the one that'll actually be used). When you've found the critical difference, you'll need to edit your zsh init file(s) to get your `PATH` set up the way it needs to be.